# Unable to find partitioner class - Cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Can some help me in fixing the below issue facing with Cassandra, when i run my application on Hadoop.

When i run the application, i am getting the below error with respect to the partitioner class we mentioned in the application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find partitioner class 'org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner'
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.getInputPartitioner(ConfigHelper.java:426)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.validateConfiguration(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:85)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.validateConfiguration(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:74)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
        at com.test.cassandratest.WcJob.run(WcJob.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at com.test.cassandratest.WcJob.main(WcJob.java:104)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to find partitioner class 'org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner'
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:458)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.construct(FBUtilities.java:470)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.newPartitioner(FBUtilities.java:416)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ConfigHelper.getInputPartitioner(ConfigHelper.java:422)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/github/jamm/MemoryMeter$Guess
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ObjectSizes.<clinit>(ObjectSizes.java:34)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner.<clinit>(RandomPartitioner.java:45)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.classForName(FBUtilities.java:450)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.github.jamm.MemoryMeter$Guess
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running with Random Partitioner? Default on Cassandra 2.0 is murmur3

Comment: I tried adding MURMUR3 initially, b/c the same issue came i changed it to RandomPartitioner!!! @RussS

Comment: Which version of JAMM is on your classpath?

Comment: Raja, Did you got solution?.  I am also  hitting the same issue. Please can you help me?.

Comment: i did not get answer for this. Currently i aborted that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem when upgraded Cassandra to 2.1 in our system, and the root cause is as following.

The jamm version Cassandra 2.1 uses is 3.0.0, and older Cassandra was using 2.5. So please update the jamm version you use, and you problem may be fixed.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.jbellis/jamm/0.3.0